# Как правильно нужно писать кавычки в ресурсах

Tags: java, android

Нужно отобразить кавычки в тексте, как правильно, нужно прописать в ресурсах стринг, что бы кавычки отобразились на экране?

Есть такая строка:

```
<string name="dialog_popup_screen_on">Only when screen "on"</string>
```

Пробовала:

```
<string name="dialog_popup_screen_on">Only when screen &quot; on &quot;</string>
```

Но кавычки не отображаются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для кавычек что одинарных, что двойных надо `\"` и `\'`.

```
<string name="dialog_popup_screen_on">Only when screen \"on\"</string>
```